# Unable to access "this" inside promise in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, this

The following function is used to find the country-code of the user and store it in the local Storage. However, I am unable to access this inside the promise and the console log returns "null".

```
  successfulLookup(position) {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    fetch(`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${latitude}+${longitude}&key=d2c9d6477126472fbe51b721a2d34399`)
      .then((response) => { return response.json() })
      .then((jsonRes) => {
        console.log(jsonRes.results[0].components.country_code);   
        console.log(this); 
        this.dataSharingService.universalLocalStorageSetter(jsonRes.results[0].components.country_code,"countryCode");
      })  
  }
```

I am calling the function findCountry inside NgOnInit

```
 findCountry() {
    if (window.navigator.geolocation) {
      window.navigator.geolocation
        .getCurrentPosition(this.successfulLookup);
    }
  }
```

The following question has been asked a couple of times and the solution is to use Arrow function but I am already using an Arrow function. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
  successfulLookup(position) {
    const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
    const self = this;
    fetch(`https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${latitude}+${longitude}&key=d2c9d6477126472fbe51b721a2d34399`)
      .then((response) => { return response.json() })
      .then((jsonRes) => {
        console.log(jsonRes.results[0].components.country_code);   
        console.log(self); 
        self.dataSharingService.universalLocalStorageSetter(jsonRes.results[0].components.country_code,"countryCode");
      })  
  }
```

tried defining const self=this

Comment: Before fetch, try to define const self = this and then use self in your console log.

Comment: `.getCurrentPosition((position) => this.successfulLookup(position))`. Lot's of questions on stackoverflow with this

Comment: @PierreBurton it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the code like

```
window.navigator.geolocation
    .getCurrentPosition(this.successfulLookup.bind(this));
```

We need to use bind(this) to the successfulLookup method because that method is calling by the getCurrentPosition. In that case, this refers to the getCurrentPosition.

I posted the concept of a bind in my youtube videos. If you are interested you can check the link. I also posted an angular course that has about 100 videos covering all the concepts. Here is the link below.

[Leela Web Dev](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1J-YH25LCjvLnFjy7WDqGA)